# Gzipped files are served via S3 but Access Denied on Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

I have the file

http://d3q6uu7asevdsg.cloudfront.net/1.2/js/link_texting_multi.js

And I want to be able to also access http://d3q6uu7asevdsg.cloudfront.net/1.2/js/link_texting_multi.js.gz

but the second one always gives a 403.

Anyone have an understanding of why this would happen? I've made the files public, tried all I can think of

Comment: Wait... do you have two objects, .js and .js.gz, in the bucket?  Or just one, .js?

Comment: Both. I ended up actually creating link_texting_multi_gz.js that is a gzipped file but with content encoding set to gzip. Cloud front won't serve .gz files it seems

Comment: Is the zipped file publicly accessibly?